# How to index only specific (based on value of attribute) records in Thinking Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Let's assume that we have a table `users`.

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id    INT,
  guest BOOL,
  name  VARCHAR(255)
)
```

I would like to index using Thinking Sphinx only records with `guest equal to false`.
At this moment I have:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :user, with: :active_record do
  indexes :name
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index definitions have a `where` method to apply conditions to the generated SQL for indices:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :user, with: :active_record do
  indexes name

  where "users.guest = FALSE"
end
```